# Is it worth putting potato skins in chicken stock?

Tags: freezing, potatoes, stock, chicken-stock

I like to save vegetable scraps (carrot tops, onion skins and ends, ends of celery etc.) in my freezer and once I have a chicken carcass and a full bag of scraps I will make chicken stock out of them. I often have left-over potato peels and I've thought of putting them in. Will they contribute in any way to the stock?

Comment: Perhaps.  If you like the flavor of earth.

Answer (score 5):

I personally would not put potato skins in my chicken stock. The flavor does not complement the other elements, and the starches you will get will cloud the stock and make it a bit grainy.